Rubymine doesn't recognise .jb file types in New View File dialog
In rubymine, when working on a rails project, if i got the a controller action, in the left margin there is a file icon, when i click it it opens either the associated view for that action, or a dialog to create a view.
I'm using the jb gem for json views, and i want the .jb file type to appear in this dropdown list. Does anyone know how to add it? At the moment it only shows ERB, HTML, Text
Thanks


This looks to me like a feature request for the vendor, not a programming problem that any of us can fix.

Someone closed my question because "its not about software tools primarily used by programmers". Its one of the most popular IDEs!!. no wonder people don't want to use SO anymore. anytime you come here to ask a question chatGPT can't answer you get told to go away.

At the moment, it's not supported, so please add your vote to the corresponding feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-33686/Add-jb-to-the-New-view-file-menu
